# Chapters of a Book and Story Structure of McKee

Tags: technique, structure, book

Considering the "story structure" proposed by Robert McKee; like:

A story is a large structure composed by acts which are composed by sequences which are composed by scenes, which are composed by (trivial events, story events, and beats).

Is it possible to say that (in general and considering modern books) acts are the chapters of a book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember about story structure and McKee, and as far as a quick search on google yielded,

### No.

Acts are larger than chapters, in most books of medium lenght. Acts are actually a concept more closely related to theater plays and screenwriting, but still it can be applied to novel and to story structure in general. If you consider that the most famous structure models are the 3-acts structure and the 5-acts one, it's quite clear that acts are larger.

By your definition, if scenes are composed by trivial events, story events, and beats, then a chapter should be a scene or a collection of scenes depending on how you "package" it.